# Alternative SSH Server (library)

Tags: python, ssh, sftp

I would like to implement my own SSH Server with independent User Management and white-listing for allowed commands on the shell but as compatible as possible.

The only Python solution I know about is Paramiko, seems a little bit complex and I read a lot about performance problems.

Other solutions are rssh, lshella and scponly. They all do basically what I need but are based 
on the /etc/passwd file for user management and use the standard ssh-server so breakouts are possible.

Basically I want a shell that only allows a user (stored in a database) to use the cmds for sftp, rsync, scp and a chrooted environment and my own disk quota management.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `paramiko` anyways. I had done pretty much exactly what you described using `paramiko` at a previous job. In fact, in addition to auth against a database and providing an sftp server, we also provided a virtual filesystem over sftp which served a database oriented view of the underlying filesystem along with custom ACL enforcement.

Your concern about complexity: I gave [a talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOPa6Sj3XAQ) about paramiko, although it is highly cringe worthy and I can't stand to watch the whole thing myself, hopefully might help you. The [slides for the talk](https://github.com/lonetwin/paramiko_talk) includes, at the bottom, references to other gentle introductory tutorials.

Your concern about performance: You really needn't worry because although there obviously is a bit of a performance difference using paramiko, you'll find that more often than not, the bottle neck would be with what happens in the application code after the ssh session is established. Paramiko by itself is pretty lightweight and acts more like a thin layer doing the connection handling. That said, if you feel like you can still limit Paramiko to just the sftp application side of things and let openssh handle all of the rest. To do this learn more about the openssh `Subsystem` config option.

Custom Auth: Check the openssh config option `AuthorizedKeysCommand`

Hope that's useful for you.